# Select Query to Update

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, ranking

I have a select query like that

```
select er.*,
       (@rank := if(@ep = exam_place_id, @rank + 1,
                    if(@ep := exam_place_id, 1, 1) 
                   )
       ) as ranking
from examresults er cross join
     (select @rank := 0, @ep := -1) params
order by exam_place_id,
         point desc;
```

I would like to update my **class_ranking** column with the values I get as **ranking** so I try to turn my select query to update like

```
      update examresults inner join
(select er.*,
       (@rank := if(@ep = exam_place_id, @rank + 1,
                    if(@ep := exam_place_id, 1, 1) 
                   )
       ) as ranking
from examresults er cross join
     (select @rank := 0, @ep := -1) params
order by exam_place_id,
         point desc
) t3 
ON examresults.O_NO = t3.O_NO
set examresults.class_ranking = t3.ranking
```

however I recieve wrong ranks on class_ranking which works correct with select query.

[image]

thanks

Comment: Delete the `;` - And you are missing `SET ...`

Comment: Please paste the full body of the error

Comment: Just changed the code sorry was pasted wrong one.

Comment: But the first query delivers the correct rankings? What is the server version?

Comment: yeah first query works correctly but with update it gives wrong ranks.

Comment: So whats your MySQL version? i guess it's MariaDB

Comment: innodb_version          | 5.7.9                        |
| protocol_version        | 10                           |
| slave_type_conversions  |                              |
| version                 | 5.7.9                        |
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Server (GPL) |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                       |
| version_compile_os      | Linux

Comment: Why don't you join ON `id`? What is your primary key?

Comment: Well id is primary key but o_no also unique which is student no

Answer (score 0):

Without sample structure and data i can't figure out why you get wrong results. For [MariaDB `ORDER BY` in a subselect](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/why-is-order-by-in-a-from-subquery-ignored/) won't work - i don't know how MySQL behaves here. A workaround would be to use `LIMIT` with a huge number. But you could aslo rewrite your select statement to an update statement:

```
update examresults er 
cross join (select @rank := 0, @ep := -1) params
set er.class_ranking = 
       (@rank := if(@ep = exam_place_id, @rank + 1,
                    if(@ep := exam_place_id, 1, 1) 
                   )
       )
order by exam_place_id,
         point desc;
```

**Update:** `UPDATE` seams not to work with `JOIN` and `ORDER BY`, so you need to eliminate that join but will have two statements:

```
select 0, 1 into @rank, @ep;

update examresults er 
-- cross join (select @rank := 0, @ep := -1) params
set er.class_ranking = 
       (@rank := if(@ep = exam_place_id, @rank + 1,
                    if(@ep := exam_place_id, 1, 1) 
                   )
       )
order by exam_place_id,
         point desc;
```

However there is another way to get the ranking joining the table with itself and counting all rows with worse or equal ranking:

```
select er.*, count(er1.id) as ranking
from examresults er
join examresults er1 
    on  er1.exam_place_id = er.exam_place_id
    and er1.point >= er.point
group by er.id
```

And the update statement would be like

```
update examresults
join (
    select er.*, count(er1.id) as ranking
    from examresults er
    join examresults er1 
        on  er1.exam_place_id = er.exam_place_id
        and er1.point >= er.point
    group by er.id
) t3 ON examresults.O_NO = t3.O_NO
set examresults.class_ranking = t3.ranking
```